# How to expire the existing JWT token?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

In my new company here is our OAuth flow

1. User enters the username and password.
2. Password service authenticates it and call to central Oauth service(developed internally).
3. Oauth service  generates some access_token(AT) and stores it in DB with expiry time.
4. Next time user comes, AT travels in cookie and application validates it with Oauth services from DB and updates the expiry time 
   to increase it in DB.

Now I am planning it to move it to JWT based authentication. Per my understanding from different tutorial , JWT token itself contains the signature
that can be verified without any storage(cache or DB). My question is on handling of expiry time increment. As I need to increase the session time
each time user comes to site, it means I need to generate new JWT token and expire the previous one.  Generating new one is easy task, Not sure how
can expire the existing JWT token ?

I can keep the map in cache containing user_id and latest JWT token. Rest of the tokens will be considered as invalid. But this cache based approach defeat
the purpose of JWT token where there should not be any requirement of any storage.

Comment: Instead of caching the original token (which is not secure), you may cache a hash of the token.

Answer (score -2):

1. The strength of JWT is the fact that its contents cannot be tampered by the end user or any attacker, because if they do, the validation will fail. So, the objective of JWT is not to avoid storage.
2. On today's date, people hardly throw away any data. JWTs are no exception. Therefore storing the JWT along with all associated details and timestamp has its value. Moreover there are some performance considerations as well. This answer will provide some details on this line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404253/1235935
3. Incrementing expiry time is handled using a second token called refresh token (can be a JWT) which usually has much longer validity than access token. If the user comes back within the validity of refresh token, the user won't have to enter credentials. This is detailed in the OAuth2 RFC.

Comment: Didn't answer the question