# Script mappers causing significant performance issues

Tags: keycloak

**The Scenario & the problem:**

1. I authenticate as a user via direct grant
2. The client I authenticate with has a series of default and optional scopes that contain custom JS script mappers to add custom claims to the token. (These scripts contain derivative logic based on group membership and group attributes)
3. I get my Access Token back and assign it as bearer token for my next request.
4. I do a http request to microservice client (see architecture below) which is routed via gateway (uses OpenFeign). (*Both gateway and microservice clients use authorization to define resources that are permission controlled.*)
5. **Problem:** As I am going through the gateway the client adapter (spring boot) hits `POST /auth/realms/*/protocol/*/token/` which causes to go through all the JS mappers again (going directly to the client server avoids this). The JS mappers add 2000ms to begin with but load testing this with anything above 30 concurrent users maxes the CPU to 100% causing a bottleneck and adds on average 10000ms to the actual request.

I am not too sure if this is the correct way to implement things. But I am looking for any advice on what can be done. Complete redesign is very expensive and I would appreciate any alternatives to this problem.

**The Architecture:**

I have a suite of spring boot microservices that have a gateway in front of it that uses Eureka discovery client.

The diagram somewhat illustrates the architecture, however, it is missing the fact that the client would authenticate before this and retrieve a token from Keycloak.

[image: Diagram]

**Clients**

I have a mixture of clients that use a mixture of auth flows

Comment: Why your microservice is calling token endpoint for the request which already has a bearer header with the access token?

Comment: Like Jan Garaj said - you might not need to call token endpoint in each microservice. Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394912/how-to-authenticate-json-web-tokens-jwt-across-different-apis/55398953#55398953

Comment: As far as I understand this is the default behaviour for official Java adapters? I don't specifically call anything - I am using the adapters provided. It seems to be using the UMA flow, because the clients have protected resources. I'm still researching at this point so not updated the question yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the adapters to Java will have a significant impact. In my experience this preview feature (JS script mappers) is not fit for production - at least not to the level we are using it on our system.

Below gatling tests clearly show that Java mappers provide 10x+ performance boost.

> The performance with using JS mappers

[image]

> The performance with using Java mappers

[image]